# How to enable interactive shell in Yocto for a BeagleBoneBlack?

Tags: beagleboneblack, yocto

I am having a yocto project which builds fine and runs as expected (on my BBB). The image is configured to autostart an application and print the output to the console (serial via FTDI). What I am trying to do in general is to disable the autostart application (already done) and instead run an interactive shell.

My question would now be, just in general, what do I need to do to enable the serial console prompt for my yocto image? Like enable additional features in local.conf or even machine features or simply add a shell to IMAGE_INSTALL? Hope someone can tell me some details about that.
My question would now be, just in general, what do I need to do to enable the serial console prompt for my yocto image? Like enable additional features in local.conf or even `MACHINE_FEATURES` or simply add a shell to `IMAGE_INSTALL`? Hope someone can tell me some details about that.

**Appendix:**

Here is my uEnv.txt:

```
bootpart=0:1
bootfile=zImage
console=ttyO0,115200n8
fdtaddr=0x88000000
fdtfile=zImage-${DTB_FILE}
loadaddr=0x82000000
mmcroot=/dev/mmcblk0p2 ro
mmcrootfstype=ext4 rootwait
optargs=consoleblank=0
mmcargs=setenv bootargs console=\${console} \${optargs} root=\${mmcroot} 
rootfstype=\${mmcrootfstype}
loadfdt=run findfdtfile; load mmc \${bootpart} \${fdtaddr} 
\${bootdir}/\${fdtfile}
loadimage=load mmc \${bootpart} \${loadaddr} \${bootdir}/\${bootfile}
uenvcmd=if run loadfdt; then echo Loaded \${fdtfile}; if run loadimage; then run mmcargs
bootz \${loadaddr} - \${fdtaddr}; fi; fi;
```

Comment: Some information about the Yocto version use: DISTRO = "poky"
DISTRO_NAME = "Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro)"
DISTRO_VERSION = "2.1.2"
DISTRO_CODENAME = "krogoth"

Answer (score 0):

From what I see [here](https://github.com/jumpnow/meta-bbb/blob/pyro/conf/machine/beaglebone.conf#L25), it is already enabled.
I don't have the opportunity now to build an image, but check UART is enabled in the `uEnv.txt`. This is not a Yocto specific problem, but a BBB one.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the information, I'll check on that. Besides, the project I am working on does not use the meta-bbb layer at all, therefor merging the additional info from the beaglebone.conf into my config might be helpful.

Comment: I don't know on what you're working, but in general, if you use the exact same board, I would advise you to use standard layers and add your bbappends. They are minimalist and consistent. Also, maintainers are doing great jobs at handling new features. It means less jobs for you and better reliability on your ecosystem

Comment: I checked out the meta-bbb and set it in bblayers.conf. But still, after the boot printouts on console it remains inaccessable, so no login prompt. I added my uEnv.txt to my original post. I am trying to compare the config files from this tutorial http://www.jumpnowtek.com/beaglebone/BeagleBone-Systems-with-Yocto.html with mine to find any differences to the machine config, but yet I havent found anything, that points to a solution.